For 60 gram protein per day, how much exercise is too much?
Following the rule of 0.8 grams of protein per kilograms or in pounds , 0.36 grams of protein per pound, I eat 60 grams of protein since I weigh 70 kg or approx 155 pounds and I exercise moderately. My workout consists of :
Barbell squat with 2 bags weighing 6 kg each - 3sets * 5 reps
dips -  3 sets * 5 reps
pull ups - 3 sets * 4 reps
v sit for abs - 3 sets holding for 40 sec
All I can eat is 60 grams protein nothing more.
my goal is to be energetic and productive and maintain some muscle mass.
From my research , I found body weight exercises are sufficient for my needs. I also found out HIIT to be a good option. Cycling would just mean more cardio which I do not want.
so am I working out more than how much I eat ? How can I asses ? Should I change the exercises or look into alternatives like HIIT ?
Thanks in advance!

What are you trying to do? What are your goals?  0.8 g/kg is sufficient protein for not dying, but if you have goals related to building muscle, you’re way short of where you should be to really optimize for that goal.

@Thomas Markov , My goal is to build muscle slowly. If you say that's not enough then How can I change my exercises for goal of being more productive and not for building muscle, which I think I will do when I'm ready ?

The only strategy necessary for building muscle slowly is “don’t do drugs”. Muscle building is a slow process, and at 0.8 g/kg with only really light weight resistance training, you’re probably closer to building almost no muscle at all, rather than building muscle slowly.

ok, I understand, Thanks. Moving on...  Pls lemme know what must be done now even tho I just can't increase my protein intake?

You can either increase your protein intake, or you can accept that you'll struggle to build any muscle. Why can't you increase your protein intake? Do you have a medical problem preventing higher protein intakes, such as a urea cycle disorder, or is this by choice?

Also, how old are you? How tall are you? Age will affect the amount of protein your body requires for muscle maintenance.

I'm voting to close this question because there are too many variables to consider here, we can't objectively answer how much exercise per gram of protein for this one person is enough or too much. For how much growth? What about the rest of the calories? etc

@Luciano          I am 19 years old. I am  5 feet 9 inch tall


Am I working out more than how much I eat? How can I asses ?Should I change the exercises or look into alternatives like HIIT?

That are three questions.
I'll focus on the first two, since I have no idea how to judge the third and it seems to be somewhat unrelated.

Am I working out more than how much I eat?

Research shows: Most likely not

[00:02:01] Jonathan Wolf: Should we all be worrying about getting enough protein?
[00:02:05] Dr. Christopher Gardner: No.

https://zoe.com/learn/podcast-should-i-eat-more-protein
The basis of this statement is:
The RDA is about .8 g/kg.
That is sufficient for over 97% of the population.
Since the demand is on a bell curve it also means it is way more then most people need.
Most people actually already do eat way more than that, like twice as much!
If you are actually trying to eat lots of protein, you probably are already taking in more then that.
But you want to gain muscles, right?
They actually do an example calculation.
If you want to gain about 10kg of pure muscle in a year,
you need about 10g of protein extra per day, which is well covered by the extra protein the average person already eats.
So if you aren't a weird outlier, that need WAY more protein than the average person and its WAY less protein than the average person, you have plenty of protein.
Some relevant quotes from https://zoe.com/learn/podcast-should-i-eat-more-protein. Sorry they are a little verbose since it is a transcript of a podcast.

when they did this for a bunch of people, as you might imagine, what they found out is, oh my God, this person in the room needed more. Than that person in the room. And when they combined their data with a bunch of other folks who had done this same disgusting thing they came up with in math, get ready for this, a normal distribution curve, which means, ah, couple people needed very little, couple people needed a lot. There's a bell curve, so there was an average in the middle. They did arrive at what would be the average. Okay. And it's called the E.A.R. It's very specific in this huge nutrition book, the Estimated Average Requirement. Now, here's an important question for you to think about. When you wanna come up with protein recommendations for the country, what would you suggest recommending? Would you recommend the estimated average requirement? Because if everyone in the country got exactly the estimated average requirement, by definition, how many people would be deficient? Half because it's the average, if you only get the average amount, the half of you that are above average, not just intelligently, but from protein requirement would be deficient. And so this happens in protein and all the vitamins and minerals, Jonathan. So when the US comes up with recommended daily allowances for protein, vitamins, and minerals, the standard approaches to take two standard deviations above the average, and in mathematical terms, that means you've picked a number that should be adequate for 97 and a half percent of the population, and there might be a couple people in the tail that need even higher than that, but it would be so few that you're pretty safe recommending that amount. Now, not only is that mount adequate, but another math thing to keep in mind here is if really everybody in the US or the UK, wherever got exactly that, 97 and a half percent, two standard deviations higher, how many would be exceeding their requirement? Oh, actually like 97%, now 97.


And so what that takes us to is they came up with a number that said 0.8 grams of protein per kilogram of body weight should meet that. And so I have a graph and a table that I can't show you because we have a podcast here, but for a lot of people, That RDA level would be maybe 40, maybe 50, maybe 60 grams of protein if, if you're heavier. Uh, so I have some US data that shows how much protein people eat in the US and it's pretty much double the EAR or double the RDA, just eating food. Not even trying. And so to me it's sort of this American idea of, God, let's see. That's what the RDA is, but I know I'm above average, so let me make sure I get some extra here. And it's like, no, you don't understand the concept. It was built in to recognize that some people would need more.


You went to the gym to lift weights and gain muscle. So you probably want more than 0.8 grams per kilogram per day. So you can put muscle on. Okay, so lemme tell you, let me tell you how many extra grams of protein you need. So Jonathan, how ambitious would it be to put on 22 pounds or 10 kilos of pure muscle? In one year. Would that be pretty good?


[00:19:43] Jonathan Wolf: That, that, I have to say sounds quite ambitious. I think if anybody saw me, they would say totally ridiculous and impossible. But let's go with, um, ambitious. Shall we?
Join our mailing list


[00:19:55] Dr. Christopher Gardner: Okay. Ambitious. So 10 kilos. Uh, actually 70% of your muscle is water. Okay. So if you were gonna do that in a year, all you'd actually have to a. Is three kilos of extra amino acids or 3000 grams of extra amino acids. Divide that into 365 days of the year and just roughly, that means you would need an extra 10 grams of protein a day to keep, retain, in addition to meeting your maintenance needs to put this on.

